# OOP generic practice (Symfony demo)

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I have two simple questions regarding OOP practice of classes. I expect that the answers will lean toward subjective preferences.

1. Let's say we have a class like a blog POST, which has private variables such as id, author, etc. I see in Symfony demo project the getter and setter methods are declared for almost each variable specifically. If the list is long, this seems quite tedious. So what about creating a method like the following?

---

```
 function setProp($variable, $val){
        if($variable !== 'id'){
            $this->$$variable = $val;
        }
    }
```

2. I see that the Symfony demo created three entity classes: Comment, Post, User. The `addComment` and `removeComment` methods are in Post class and takes a typecast argument of Comment class. Can we make a `removeComment` method in the Comment class itself? Because I feel that most of the time the comment *id* would be the first piece of info passed to the script, so why not have such a method handy in the class itself? And is it 'bad' to have repeated methods that perform the same job in different classes?

Comment: Might be better off writing a few apps and then see about refining things.  There are a number of ways to automatically generate getter/setter functions.  And the form component relies heavily up on them.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of accessor methods is to provide a way to hook into the action of setting or getting a property.

For basic operations, you don't need accessor methods. They may seem pointless just assigning or returning a value.

One of the main purposes of accessor methods is restricting access to a property. You may want, under some conditions, to prevent the changing of a property. If the property is public, there is nothing you can do to prevent writing to the property. But if your property is private and you have a setter, then you may just not set the property under certain conditions.

```
private $allowed = true;
private $data;

public function getData() {
    return $this->data;
}

public function setData($data) {
    if ($this->allowed) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}

public function block() {
    $this->allowed = false;
}
```

In this example, you may block write-access to the `data` property by setting the `allowed` property to `false`.

There are many other cases that make use of accessors (storing data outside the object, converting values, etc.)

It is good practice to use setters and getters from the start because if you create them later, you have to replace all references to the property with references to the setter/getter.

Answer (score 0):

you can look at magique method __set (http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) but it's better to write each setXxxx